# journalctl - clear low priority messages

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

Is there a way to clear systemd/journal messages manually only keeping high priority messages?

I have a system with very limited storage and would like to keep the journal compact while still keeping track of errors.
Messages of priority 0..3 should be kept as long as there is sufficient space, messages of lower priority can be cleared if they are older than a day.

Can the --vacuum-time option of journalctl be combined with any type of filter?

Comment: Could you please update with your journald.conf configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to clear systemd/journal messages manually only keeping high priority messages?

No.

> Can the --vacuum-time option of journalctl be combined with any type of filter?

No.

Your options are:

- Not logging
- Logging outside of journald
- Logging somewhere else if your have a network connection

Comment: Thanks, I'll set up a (daily) cron job to periodically save high priority messages to a separate log and clear the journal. Something like `journalctl -p 5..0 --since="24 hours ago" | gzip >> error.log.gz`